# Max of each 2D matrix in 4D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4D array, which is defined as follows:

```
B = np.array(
    [[[[0.5000, 0.5625],
       [0.5000, 0.5625]],

      [[1.2500, 0.5000],
       [0.5625, 0.6875]],

      [[0.5625, 0.6250],
       [0.5000, 0.5625]]]]
)
```

I want to take the max of each 2D matrix, such that I get a result of:

```
array([0.5625, 1.250, 0.6250])
```

Similarly, I want to take the min of each 2D matrix, such that I get a result of:

```
array([0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000])
```

However, when doing `np.max(B, axis=0)`, `np.max(B, axis=1)`, `np.max(B, axis=2)`, or `np.max(B, axis=3)` -- none of these gives the right answer. Is there another argument I need to specify to do this operation?

The correct solution should not use any loops and ideally one function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is a misunderstanding of how the `axis` argument works. For most of these aggregation methods the `axis` keyword is the axis (or axes) to project *along*, i.e. these axes are "removed" from the result. So in this case you want to call something like:

```
In [7]: B.max((0, 2, 3))                                                                                                            
Out[7]: array([0.5625, 1.25  , 0.625 ])
```

same thing for `min`

```
In [8]: B.min((0, 2, 3))                                                                                                            
Out[8]: array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

Or you can call the `numpy` method directly

```
In [9]: np.max(B, axis=(0, 2, 3))                                                                                                   
Out[9]: array([0.5625, 1.25  , 0.625 ])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape it into a 2d array of the desired subarrays, then apply your max or min function on each subarray:

```
>>> B.reshape(3, 4)
array([[0.5   , 0.5625, 0.5   , 0.5625],
       [1.25  , 0.5   , 0.5625, 0.6875],
       [0.5625, 0.625 , 0.5   , 0.5625]])
>>> B.reshape(3, 4).max(axis=1)
array([0.5625, 1.25  , 0.625 ])
>>> B.reshape(3, 4).min(axis=1)
array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```